# macports not response at terminal

Tags: command, macports

I installed Macports on Yosemite as follows;

```
Install MacPorts for your version of OS X: 
    1). http://www.macports.org/install.php
    2). OS X 10.10 Yosemite - click
    3). sudo port -v selfupdate
        sudo: port: command not found
```

After restart terminal these happens.

```
NeoStoryHackin:~ windstory$ sudo port install krusader
NeoStoryHackin:~ windstory$ sudo port -v selfupdate
NeoStoryHackin:~ windstory$ sudo port upgrade outdated
NeoStoryHackin:~ windstory$ port echo leaves
Bus error: 10
```

And this is the path of "~/.bash_profile".

```
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

Any comment would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by installing macports through 'svn checkout http://svn.macports.org/repository/macports/trunk'.